# AWS msk config update in brokers

Tags: aws-msk

Currently I am using a Kafka cluster HDinsight from azure and able to update the config by login to the broker/console. Planning to use the AWS msk to replace the HDinsight, I am able to create cluster and able create topics. Now I want to add the advertised listeners for each customer. Please suggest how can I do that?